# how can I edit BizReview Drupal theme

Tags: fonts, drupal-7, themes, font-face

hello and tnx for your help

I installed a BizRiview drupal theme on my domain : www.tourmap.ir

and I want to change font- face of my site and i want to insert a persian font called "YEKAN" i added font-face code to custom style sheet but my site doesent change thank too all for your helps

Comment: Show us more details - how did you insert that font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this theme is one that you can alter safely, meaning it is not a base theme that will be updated regularly, and will risk you overwriting any changes you have made to it, you can do this:

- Open up the BizRiview theme dir.
- Add your css file to said dir (the assumption being made here is that there is not a css dir, if there is, add it to the css dir and prepend the name of the dir to the name of the stylesheet in the instructions below).
- Open the .info file in the theme dir.
- Add this line to the info file:
  `stylesheets[all][] = Name-of-your-stylesheet.css`